# Getting Data via a PHP Curl Call

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, postman

I am trying to make a PHP Curl Call. The call works in POSTMAN and looks like :

```
URL Endpoint: https://api.sb.example.com/v1/resource/identifier

Headers: 
Content Type: application/json
Authorization : Bearer AccessTokenValue

HTTP Protocol : GET
```

This call returns me a valid JSON response. Now when i do the same using PHP, i am unable to get the response. Here is my PHP Curl call:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sb.example.com/v1/resource/identifier");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type : application/json',
                                            'Authorization : Bearer AccessTokenValue'
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
curl_close($ch);
```

This call via PHP gives me the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Any ideas/suggestions for the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Add below said lines before curl_exec()

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);                                         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out, i had a space in headers array in KeyValue pair.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type : application/json', ..)
```

it should have been

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
```